# Spring JPA Repository is unable to create mapping tables of my entities

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, h2

I'm using spring data with H2 database and it's not creating database tables for my entity objects.

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/app_db
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

DomainApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(DefaultPersistenceConfig.class)
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.sample.Domain.modal"})
public class DomainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DomainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

DefaultPersistanceConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.sample.Domain.model" }, entityManagerFactoryRef = "defaultEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "defaultTransactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DefaultPersistenceConfig {

    @Autowired
    public DataSource defaultDataSource;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Qualifier("defaultEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean defaultEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder.dataSource(defaultDataSource).persistenceUnit("hib-unit")
                .packages("com.sample.Domain.model").build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Qualifier("defaultTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager defaultTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
    }
}
```

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GENERAL_LEDGER_TRANSACTION")
public class GeneralLedgerTransaction implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id = 0L;
....
```

JPA Repository interface:

```
@Repository
public interface GeneralLedgerTransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<GeneralLedgerTransaction, Long> {    
    }
```

When I run the application and make a rest call to the controller to fetch data from the repository, it should return an empty array but I keep getting an error below.

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "GENERAL_LEDGER_TRANSACTION" not found; SQL statement:
select ... from GENERAL_LEDGER_TRANSACTION generalled0_ [42102-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197] ...

Answer (score 0):

add `spring.datasource.initialize=true` in your application.properties

Comment: Hi, no it doesn't work also it shows that property is deprecated

Comment: thanks for trying but I created a new project following online guide and moved my entities and repositories over. It's working now.